file_put_contents fails only when accessed from cURL
I have a page that I use for retrieving data that I want to curl via a cron job once a day. When it's run, it's supposed to fetch some data, process it, and then write it to a series of files with file_put_content.
Everything works perfectly when I visit the URL in browser - the data is correct, and it writes to files with no issue. When I curl the URL with a cron job, the data is processed like it should be, but the file writes fail. I made it create a log to record its actions, and in each log every action is reported as successful, except for the file writes when I'm curling via cron.
I tried visiting my file permissions to see if that might be the issue, current file permissions for the scripts that are doing the writing are 0664.
Let me know if this is not enough code to understand what's going on, this is the function that calls the file write function. It takes an existing data array, makes a copy, checks for updates, and updates if necessary. Then, it compares the updated variable to the copied variable to the start and only writes to file if they differ.
function updateData() {
        /*
        Data processing happening up here ^^

        $log is a large string that keeps track of outputs from functions so I can check what happened during cron events - this gets written as well later, but never has any issues with this
        */
        if ($jsonData!==$jsonDataMirror)
            {
            //File write function referenced below, uses file_put_contents
            $fileWrite = writeJSON($jsonData,"geo/".$customer['id']);
            $log .= "<br />".$customer['customer_id']." file write was ";
            if ($fileWrite)
                {
                $log .= "successful.";
                }
            else
                {
                $log .= "unsuccessful.";
                }
            }
}

And here is the function that actually calls file_put_contents:
   function writeJSON($data,$file) {
//If there are empty array keys, we won't write those to the index
if (isset($data[""]))
        {
        unset($data[""]);
        }
    //Add backslashes to single quotes, since the JSON encoded data will go into a PHP string
    $theData=str_replace("'","\\'",json_encode($data));
        //Actual file output
        $output='<?php
        $json=\''.$theData.'\';
        $JSONdata=json_decode($json,true);
        return $JSONdata;
            ?>';
    //Write to file
    $file=file_put_contents(__DIR__ . "/data/".$file.".php",$output);
    //Return true or false based on whether the file write was successful
    if ($file==false)
        {
        return false;
        }
    return true;
}


I'm not sure how this could happen. The PHP script is being run via the same webserver in both cases. Script permissions don't depend on the client. Does the script do anything that depends on the user agent?

When file_put_contents() fails, what is the error message?

Are you posting any form data when you go to the URL in the browser?

Please post a [mre].

I've seen browser debugging tools that gave you an equivalent curl commandline invocation. Verify your claim that something only happens with cURL with that base.

@Barmar thanks for the advice, I'm still new to how to format these questions best - I just updated this post with the code that is happening when these file writes fail - the only error message I have is that the file_put_contents returned falsey - which then writes into the $log that I have going (I read the log after the event, that's when I caught this). And no, the URL is being accessed directly, so no post data. There are URL parameters, but they have no bearing on these functions at all.

Make sure you have error_reporting(E_ALL); enabled. When file_put_contents() returns false, it should either print or log a warning with the reason.

Hi @austinl and welcome to SO!

You do not show the page that is accessed, only functions. Please provide the actual page you access via browser or cURL.
This code looks like a bad idea. I only took a quick look at it but to me it looks like you are creating a backdoor into your server.


Hi @SvenTUM, thanks! 1. These functions are what is happening on the page that is being accessed; these functions work correctly when the page is visited in browser, but do not work when accessed via cURL. I don't want to link the actual pages its using as I don't want to expose my file structure here. 2. Do you mean the actual output of the file? There is a portion of the script that I removed that authenticates a nonce against the database, but I wanted to remove the fluff for the sake of this post. Is that what you were talking about?
